# Add script to specific layout or pages in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to load google analytics tags in my PublicLayout and not inside other layouts.

PublicLayout.js:

```
<Script src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}/>
<Script>
  {`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}');`}
</Script>
```

The problem is that when I change my layout to PrivateLayout using `next/link`, these tags won't remove from body of html.

Folder Structure:

```
node_modules
public
src
-- components
---- Layouts
------ PublicLayout.js
------ PrivateLayout.js
-- pages
---- admin
------ products
---- _app.js
---- _document.js
---- index.js
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your foldeer structure?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar - I've added folder structure to the end of the question.

Comment: How are you adding those Layouts for each pages? Are you adding those on per page or added in `_app.js` file?